# Load data from DynamoDB to Snowflake using Matillion

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dynamodb-queries, matillion

I am trying to load data from dynamo Db to snowflake using matillion (DynamoDB Query Compoenent)
Our client Matillion is hosted on one AWS account(XYZ) and Dynamo DB is in another Aws account(ABC).
I need help to connect matillion cross account connection with AWS. Seeking help to know how to make such connection in below highlighted settings
[image: Matillion settings]

Answer (score 0):

While I've never used matillion I would suggest an alternative approach. Instead of trying to setup cross account access why not export the DynamoDB table to an S3 bucket in account XYZ. Then use matillion to take the data from S3 to Snowflake.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/S3DataExport.HowItWorks.html